# How to decrease the length of the vertical line in the array environment globally?

Tags: arrays, lengths

First a minimal working sample is as follows.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\delimitershortfall=10pt
\delimiterfactor=000
\begin{document}
\[
S=\left\{x~
\begin{array}{|l}
\frac{m}{n}
\end{array}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, I make the braces become smaller by setting the value of `\delimiterfactor`. While the vertical line in the array environment is still very long. So how to decrease the length of the vertical line in the array environment globally?

---

---

The problem disappears after using `\middle|` to produce the long "such that" line (*S* is a set of *x* such that ...) as follows.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\delimitershortfall=10pt
\delimiterfactor=000
\begin{document}
\[
S=\left\{x~\middle|
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{m}{n}
\end{array}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remark: Usually people compose such structure with `\left\{ x \middle| \frac{m}{n} \right\}`

Comment: @F.Pantigny It's a typical example, and we may also have long and long vertical lines in big and big sets.

Comment: the array vertical bar really isn't meant to be used as a symbol and can't easily be made shorter, it's a tex primitive `\vrule` so it always fills its surrounding box `\middle|` is certainly the expected markup here and will grow to the same size as your `{}` automatically

Comment: @M.Logic what do you mean by "long and long vertical lines in big and big sets." ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got it. `\midddle|` also works for many lines of texts after` |`.  I thought it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: `\middle` is exactly the same as `\left` and `\right` but you can have any number of them between a left and right and all marked symbols grow in the same way

Comment: @F.Pantigny Thanks! The problem disappear, and I add some comments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use neither `array` nor `\middle`. Perhaps `\big` size, but it depends on the contents.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\[
S=\{x \mid \tfrac{m}{n} \}
\]

\[
S=\bigl\{x \bigm| \tfrac{m}{n} \bigl\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, one can do better for set builder notation.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\NewDocumentCommand{\set}{s o >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}{%
  % first we absorb the arguments and pass control to \makeset
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \makeset{\left\{}{\right\}}{\;\middle|\;}#3%
  }{%
    \makeset
      {\mathopen{\IfValueT{#2}{#2}\{}}% opening
      {\mathclose{\IfValueT{#2}{#2}\}}}% closing
      {\mathrel{\IfValueT{#2}{#2}|}}% middle
      #3%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeset}{mmmmm}{%
  #1% opening
  #4\IfValueT{#5}{#3#5}%
  #2%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
S=\set{x | \tfrac{m}{n}}
\\
S=\set[\big]{x | \tfrac{m}{n}}
\\
S=\set*{x | \frac{m}{n}}
\\
S=\set{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Advantages: you're not tied to a particular representation. For instance, if you want to add thin spaces at either end when there is a bar (Knuth does this), you can do it by modifying `\makeset`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeset}{mmmmm}{%
  #1% opening
  \IfValueT{#5}{\,}%
  #4\IfValueT{#5}{#3#5\,}%
  #2%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Also a good solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With `nicematrix` you can define a custom line style that is shortened by any amount you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
    {custom-line={letter=I, tikz={shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt}}}
\[
\begin{NiceArray}{cIc}
  x & \frac{m}{n}
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since I could pick one solution only, I vote yours but pick @egreg 's one.